# I need help for this issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Let say I have a table with two columns. In reality it is going to be in two different table but to make it simple lets use one table. I just want to know how I can tackle this issue

```
     A   |     B
------------------------
 2016-01 |  2015-00
 2016-02 |  2015-01 
 2017-01 |  2017-01
 2018-00 |  2018-01
```

How can I write a query that pick column `A` and compare it with column `B`.

I want

- `2016-01` correspond to `2015-01`
- `2016-02` to `2015-01`
- `2017-01` to `2017-01`
- `2018-00` to `2017-01` (since `2018-00` is less than `2018-01`)

How can I make sure that column `A` only picks a value from column `B` where column `A` is is greater than column `B`.

I tried writing a query as

```
SELECT A FROM TB1 WHERE '1016-01' >= (SELECT MAX(B) FROM TB1)
```

but this query wont work because `max(b)` will always return `2017-01

Comment: it's a self-join: `select * from foo left join foo AS bar on foo.A > bar.B`

Comment: The hypothetical issue and the real issue are completely different.

Comment: Why don't you write it up the way it really is. Two tables.

Comment: let assume column A is in table A and Column B in table B. I thought about cross join but i have millions of records and that may not work ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **SQL Server** you can use something like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    ('2016-01'),('2016-02'),('2017-01'),('2018-00')
    ) as t(A)
), cte1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    ('2015-00'),('2015-01'),('2017-01'),('2018-01')
    ) as t(B)
)

SELECT  c.A,
        t.B 
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 B
    FROM cte1
    WHERE CAST(REPLACE(c.A,'-','') as int) >= CAST(REPLACE(B,'-','') as int)
    ORDER BY B DESC
    ) t
```

Will output:

```
A       B
2016-01 2015-01
2016-02 2015-01
2017-01 2017-01
2018-00 2017-01
```

The idea is to replace `-` with nothing to make values like `201501` and then compare them as `int` values.

Answer (score -1):

Use 2 different tables

```
SELECT A.Col, B.Col
FROM A JOIN B ON A.Col >= B.Col
```

Comment: They have only 1 table. And why would you use a cross join and then turn it into an inner join?

Comment: @SeanLange My bad.. you're right on the join.   Also, the actual problem is related to 2 tables as per the question